# elastic search as grafana datasource

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

Issue: Not able to get data flow from Elasticsearch to Grafana.

I can able to connect to ES Kibana from browser to URL with basic auth (user id & password).

When I hit save and test in Grafana Datasource, I don't see any errors. But, I don't see any data showing up in my grafana panel.

Datasource properties:

```
URL : http://example.com:5601 
Access: Browser
Auth: Basic Auth
Index name: same name what I used in Kibana query
Grafana Version: 7.0+
Time field name: @timestamp
Level field name: <blank>
```

I enabled CORS on ES.

Appreciate your help

Here is my Datasource configuration.

[image: DataSource Settings]

[image: Panel]

Answer (score 2):

You are using Grafana Elasticsearch datasource, but your are connecting to Kibana (typical port 5601) and not to Elasticsearch. Kibana is similar to Grafana - both are "user interfaces" for Elasticsearch. Connect datasource directly to Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thanks Jan Garaj, I tried with ES port 9200 and CORS is enabled in ES.

Answer (score 0):

The ES URL what is being configured in Grafana should return below json

```
{
   "name": "dev1234.dev.company.com",
   "cluster_name": "elasticsearch_es7test",
   "cluster_uuid": "V-QwB6jmSRCtMaMTTYW1qA",
   "version": {
     "number": "7.6.2",
     "build_flavor": "default",
     "build_type": "tar",
     "build_hash": "ef48eb35cf30adf4db14086e8aabd07ef6fb113f",
     "build_date": "2020-03-26T06:34:37.794943Z",
     "build_snapshot": false,
     "lucene_version": "8.4.0",
     "minimum_wire_compatibility_version": "6.8.0",
     "minimum_index_compatibility_version": "6.0.0-beta1"
   },
   "tagline": "You Know, for Search"
 }
```